# why a lot of login logout actions in one sqlserver session?

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledbconnection

I created ole db connection to sqlserver 2008r2 using ATL::CDataSource, then opened 
session using ATL::CSession, 
then run different sql queries using open and close rowsets CCommand. 
in the end i closed session and connection.

and then I created Audit log and add login/logout actions  to log. 
I see a lot of  login/logout actions with one session id.
looks like for each query my program makes login/logout. What  do I incorrectly?